# JavaScript DOM addeventlistener pass paramater

Tags: javascript

OK I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JavaScript index</title>
</head>
<body id="body">
<p id="para">Hello I am Sam</p>

<script>
"use strict";

var element = document.getElementById("para");

element.addEventListener( "click", function(color){
    this.style.backgroundColor = color;
}, false );


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My main question is with regards to:

```
element.addEventListener( "click", function(color){
    this.style.backgroundColor = color;
}, false );
```

Is there  a way to dynamically pass in a color or does it have to be hard coded?

Comment: how do you want to pass the color.. is it in the time of event registration or the actual click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use a named function to add the handler like

```
function addClickHandler(element, color) {
    element.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        this.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }, false);
}
```

then

```
addClickHandler(element, 'red')
```

Comment: Thanks. And may I say nicely done on using a closure.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use composition and have a function that returns a handler.

```
function createHandler( color) {
    return function (e) {
        this.style.backgroundColor = color;
    };
}

element.addEventListener( "click", createHandler('red'), false );
```

Or what I think is the most elegant of all solutions, [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```js
function clickHandler(color, e) {
  this.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var colors = ['blue', 'red', 'gray'];
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler.bind(divs[i], colors[i]), false);
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid firebrick;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Nicely done! @juan mendes. My skills and understanding in JavaScript and closures just went up 10%.

Comment: @samyismyhero Since you're learning JavaScript, I added another example that is even more abstracted, and, IMO, much cooler .